# A question about approximating a continuous function with a $G$-invariant polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, invariant-theory

Given $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a finite group $G$ and a compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, I want to prove that I can approximate $f$ with a $G$-invariant polynomial on $K$.

I think this is trivial, but I'm not 100% sure.

What I would do is the following, by Stone-Weierstrass theorem we can say that there exists a polynomial $p$ such that

$$|f(\textbf{x}) - p(\textbf{x})| < \varepsilon \, \, , \, \forall \textbf{x} \in K .$$

Then I consider the set $K_{sym} = \bigcup_{g \in G} g \cdot K$ and define $q(\textbf{x}) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_gp(g \cdot \textbf{x})$. Of course $q$ is $G$-invariant.

Can I conlcude from here, that

$$|f(\textbf{x}) - q(\textbf{x})|<\varepsilon \, \, \forall \textbf{x} \in K \, \, \, \, ?$$

EDIT:

First we consider a symmetrized domain $K_{sym} := \bigcup_{g \in G}g \cdot K$ which is still compact because is the image of the continuous map $(g,\textbf{x}) \mapsto g \cdot \textbf{x}$. So ther exists a polynomial $p$ such that

$$|f(\tilde{x})-p(\tilde{x})| < \varepsilon \, \, , \, \forall \tilde{x} \in K_{sym}.$$

But if $\tilde{x} \in K_{sym} \Rightarrow \exists g \in G$ such that $\tilde{x} = g \cdot \textbf{x}$ for some $\textbf{x} \in K$.

Then we define $q(\textbf{x}):= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}p(g \cdot \textbf{x})$ and then

$$|f(\textbf{x})-q(\textbf{x})| = |f(g \cdot \textbf{x}) - \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_g p(g \cdot \textbf{x})| \le \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_g|p(g \cdot \textbf{x}) - f(g \cdot \textbf{x})| < \varepsilon.$$

I'm trying to follow the lines explained in this work https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.09342.pdf (right under Definition 4)

Comment: How (and on what) is the action of $G$ defined? Add details to your reasoning and see if it still holds…

Comment: $G$ is a general group acting on the coordinates $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 3):

I am in doubt. Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2  \to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x$, $K=[0,1]^2$ and $G=\{I, (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)\}$. If $p$ is any polynomial, then
$$
q(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(p(x,y)+p(y,x)).
$$
Let $\varepsilon = 1/3$. Assume that $|f(x,y)-q(x,y)| < \varepsilon$ on $K$.
Then on $K$
$$
|x-q(x,y)| < 1/3, ~ |y-q(y,x)|=|y-q(x,y)|<1/3.
$$
For $x=0,y=1$ we get $|q(0,1)|< 1/3$ and $|1-q(0,1)|<1/3$, not possible.

I think this approximation is only possible if $f$ is $G$-invariant
on $K':= \cup_{g\in G} gK$, that is $f(x)=f(gx)$ $(x \in K',g \in G)$. Then your argument works.

Comment: I'm actually looking at the proof given in this work (Proposition 2.1) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10306.pdf and trying to figure out what is the difference...

Comment: I don't understand the details, but the author of this Proposition is talking about approximating "group invariant" functions by (simpler) group invariant functions. That's in accordance with what I meant with the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Actually, there is another work related to the first one https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.09342.pdf where it is stated exactly $G$-invariant polynomials can approximate an arbitrary continuous function on a compact domain .(Right under Definition 4)

Comment: I think the assertion in the second paper is wrong, as stated. If a sequence of polynomials $(q_k)$ is uniformly convergent to a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ on a compact set $K'$ containing $K$ where $K'$ is $G$-invariant and each $q_k$ is $G$-invariant then $f(x)-f(gx) = f(x)-q_k(x)+q_k(gx)-f(gx) \to 0$ for each $x \in K'$ and each $g \in G$. Thus $f$ has to be $G$-invariant on $K'$.

Comment: So even if we consider $f$ on the symmetrized domain $K'$ it doesn't mean that the function is invariant on this domain, i.e. $f(g \cdot x) = f(x)$ for $x \in K_{sym}$. Maybe I was a bit confused about this. Actually if the map $f$ is $G$-invariant it makes sense then to write $|q(x)-f(x)| = |p(g \cdot x) - f( g \cdot x)|\dots$ like they actually start to do in the paper. It's this equality that I didn't indeed understand.

Comment: but in your statement, if $x \in K'$ then shouldn't it be $f(gx) = f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

No such approximation is possible. Here is a counterexample. Let $\mathbb{Z}_2$ act on $\mathbb{R}$ by negation. The functions invariant under this $\mathbb{Z}^2$ action are the even functions. So, for instance, on $[-1,1]$, no approximation of $f(x) = x$ to within $1$ in $\sup$ norm is possible.